# Does natural deduction require a non-empty set of premises?

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, natural-deduction

Normally in a Hilbert system, writing a proof $\Delta \vdash \varphi_n$ with lines $\varphi_1, \varphi_2, ..., \varphi_n$ is done such that each $\varphi_k$ is either a proposition contained in $\Delta$, an axiom of the Hilbert system, or the result of modus ponens on two earlier lines.

In natural deduction, how does this work when we now have no axioms to work with, but rather only rules of inference? Each line could either be the result of a rule, or an element contained in $\Delta$... is that all? Does natural deduction ultimately require a non-empty $\Delta$ in order for us to even write proofs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Natural deduction systems generally have a notion of assumption introduction and discharge. The easiest-to-understand rule that needs this is $\to$-introduction. This says that if we can assume $A$ and then prove $B,$ then we can infer $A\to B$ and discharge the assumption $A,$ leaving us with an unconditional proof of $A\to B$ (i.e. a proof from the empty set).

The exact nature of how the rules work and the proofs are laid out varies from system to system. For instance, see the [hypothetical derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#Hypothetical_derivations) section of the wikipedia page.

A couple more things

1. In natural deduction, proofs aren't simply lists of statements like in Hilbert style. Often, they are trees. In one common type of system (which I have typically seen referred to as 'Fitch-style'), they are lists of statements, but have indentations to indicate when you have assumptions (i.e. when there's a 'change of context').
2. Notice that the $\to$-introduction rule is functionally the exact same thing as the deduction theorem from a Hilbert style system. In natural deduction, it comes 'for free' as an inference rule, at the cost of a somewhat more complicated structure of formal proofs.
3. Also, only the *logical* portion of a natural deduction system has no axioms. If we are working in a mathematical system, like PA or ZFC, those axioms are there, and look the same no matter what underlying implementation of first-order logic you are using. Of course, those axioms can just be thought of as assumptions to the left of the turnstile.

Comment: So technically we do need to start out with a non-empty premise set, it's just that we can potentially discharge them with $\to$-introduction?

Comment: @user525966 No, we start with the empty set (assuming we're even using a system where the proofs are lists of statements, e.g. Fitch-style). Then we *introduce* assumptions. Then we discharge them.

Comment: I don't see a rule that lets us introduce assumptions? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_2._Natural_deduction_system

Comment: @user525966 Conditional proof.

Comment: Ah... so we're allowed to add things from the lefthand side as we please, as long as we discharge them later?

Comment: @user525966 The implementation details vary from system to system. But on a high level, yes. The idea is that we can add $A$ to our context, and then prove $B,$ and then discharge and move back to the original context and have $A\to B$ proven in that context. Of course the lines in between the assumption and discharge are 'off limits' afterward since they only held in the context where $A$ was assumed. These ideas need to be made precise in a given system.

Comment: So in practice we consider a proof completed when we return back to our original context (at the very end)? We can't just "stop" partway in once we have what we need on the righthand side because we'd still have assumptions lingering about on the left?

Comment: @user525966 In practice, there are many context changes within a given proof, but yes, at the end you will have returned to the original context and you can't stop when there are still assumptions outright.

Comment: Is "fitch-style" just a way of writing ND proofs? Or is it a separate logical system "alongside" Hilbert, ND, etc?

Comment: @user525966 Re 'Fitch-style', I'm not super sharp on the distinctions. In one sense it's a family of natural deduction systems where the proofs take the shape of a sequential list of formulas at different indentation levels. In another sense, tree-style and indented-list-style proofs are inter-convertable, so Fitch is just a choice of layout.

Comment: So would it be possible to write a "fitch-style proof" for a "classic propositional Hilbert logic system"?

Comment: @user525966 No, Fitch is just for natural deduction style systems. Hilbert-style systems are sufficiently simple that there's only one good (i.e. commonly used)  layout style.

Comment: Which in the case of Hilbert would just be "writing out each line"? (assuming line-writing doesn't have a more specific name)

Comment: @user525966 yeah, which I suppose is kind of a degenerate Fitch style.

Comment: Thank you!(15char)

Answer (score 3):

Natural deduction certainly can prove theorems $\vdash \phi$ with no assumptions to the left of $\vdash$, because rules like $\Rightarrow$-introduction let you discharge (i.e., get rid of) assumptions. For examples, let's prove $\vdash A \Rightarrow A$:

1. Assume $A$.
2. Apply $\Rightarrow$-introduction discharging the assumption made in step 1 to conclude $A \Rightarrow A$.

In sequent notation, I have gone from the axiom $A \vdash A$ in step 1 to the theorem $\vdash A \Rightarrow A$ in step 2. So the sequent proof would look like:

1. $A \vdash A$ (Axiom)
2. $\vdash A \Rightarrow A$ (from 1 using $\Rightarrow$-introduction).

Comment: Isn't "assuming $A$" the same as pulling $A$ out of the assumption set $\Delta$ on the lefthand side?

Comment: No. In sequent notation, "assuming $A$"  means using the axiom $A \vdash A$.  In the proof tree notation it just means forming a leaf node labelled with $A$. I've updated my answer to show what the sequent notation deduction looks like.

Comment: That seems to be using an assumption on the lefthand side though. And to my knowledge, ND doesn't use axioms

Comment: Does my updated answer help? You seem to be mixing up the sequent notation for natural deduction which **does** need axioms like $A \vdash A$ and the tree notation which doesn't need (non-logical) axioms. (I say you seem to be mixing things up because you are talking about the lefthand side of something, a notion that only makes sense in the sequent notation, which does need axioms).

Comment: I don't understand the difference. What do you mean by treating $A \vdash A$ as an axiom vs. tree notation that doesn't need non-logical axioms?

Comment: Unfortunately the updated answer doesn't help, I'm not seeing which rules permit these actions

Comment: The rules will be called something like "ASSUME" and "$\Rightarrow$-INTRO", but you need to tell us exactly what system of natural deduction rules you are using if you can't relate them to my answer.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_2._Natural_deduction_system are these the correct rules?

Comment: The Wikipedia articles on natural deduction are not very good. Have a look at https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/.

Comment: I am having a tough time understanding this page, it's hard to see without seeing it being used

Comment: Perhaps you should try devoting a bit more than 10 minutes to it!